# Compare a string to a list of fragments in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a long list of job description titles that I need to filter by their importance to the organization. I have developed a simple heuristic for doing so. For example, if the title contains a word like "administrator" or "director," it is important. Failing this test, if it contains a word like "deputy" or "assistant" then it is not important.

This is easy to accomplish with a few lines in Python, but I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to do it. Here's where I am right now.

```
def in_fragment(phrase, fragments):
    for fragment in fragments:
        if fragment in phrase:
            return True
    return False
```

Works perfectly fine, but would love to it the right way if possible! Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use sets? (or convert your lists to sets)? Your solution is fine, is just that with sets it'd be "cleaner"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it would be using `any`:

```
def in_fragment(phrase, fragments):
    return any(x in phrase for x in fragments)
```

Comment: +1, but it might be better to turn this around to `x in fragments for x in phrase`, because then you can trivially change the `fragments` list into a set, and it'll be `O(N)` (where N is the number of words in the phrase) instead of `O(NM)` (where M is the number of fragments).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (Other solutions offered are very good and informative too, so thank you everyone.)

Answer (score 2):

Well... probably F.C.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692555/289011) is cleaner than what I'm about to write, but since I tested it on my computer with `sets`, here it goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a="this is a letter for the administrator of the company"
important = set(["administrator", "director"])

hits=important.intersection(set(a.split(" ")))
if len(hits) > 0:
    print "Wo! This is important. Found: %s" % (hits)
```

Maybe you'll find it useful... for something... **:)**

Comment: You'd probably be better of writing `hits = important.intersection(set(a.split(" "))` so you can do `len(hits)` and `… %s" % (hits,)` instead of doing all that work twice in a row. (I'm not so worried about performance, unless he has huge sets, but about readability and maintainability. Your way, it's far too easy to change one of the two expressions and not the other.)

Comment: Yep, you're right, @abanert... It was mainly for example purposes and that's why I didn't pay much attention to that but you're absolutely right (I edited the answer with your input)

Answer (score 0):

```
def rankImportance(titles, fragments):
    """titles is a list of job titles
       fragments is a list of sets. 
         At index 0: set(['administrator', 'director'])
         At index 1: set(['deputy', 'assistant'])
         etc..."""

    answer = collections.defaultdict(list)
    while titles:
        done = set()
        for i,title in enumerate(titles):
            for r,words in enumerate(fragments):
                if any(word in title for word in words):
                    answer[r].append(title)
                    delete.add(i)
        titles = [title for i,title in enumerate(titles) if i not in delete]

    return answer
```

This should return a dictionary with keys that are ranks and values that are lists of job titles. The smaller the value of the rank, the more important it is. The smallest rank will be 0.

Hope this helps